# How to clear the filter on change the tab-extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I am writing the new tab in extjs, it is replica of previous tab, but data will be same.

used route.jsp file to moving from one tab to other tab

say tab A is old and Tab B is new both are using same route.jsp (router)

```
GLOBAL_PERSON_FILTERS = ['name' 'age']
```

this was for A tab

```
this.MGridFilter = {
          ftype : 'filters',
          encode : true, // json encode the filter query
          local : true, // defaults to false (remote filtering)
          filters : [
              {
                type : 'list',
                dataIndex : 'endview',
                options : Indigo.GLOBAL_PERSON_FILTERS
              },
```

Copied the same for Tab B as well but option name was changed

```
 GLOBAL_TEST_PERSON_FILTERS = ['designation' 'company']

this.MGridFilter = {
          ftype : 'filters',
          encode : true, // json encode the filter query
          local : true, // defaults to false (remote filtering)
          filters : [
              {
                type : 'list',
                dataIndex : 'endview',
                options : Indigo.GLOBAL_TEST_PERSON_FILTERS
              },
```

But problem i am facing is when i check the filter in tab B tab A also getting affected

Please help me on this issue

Answer (score 0):

If you use filter on the same store it always get affected (there is no difference where filter will be used).
You can use Ext.data.ChainedStore on Tab B to replica store on Tab A (filter chained store dont affect Store on Tab A).

It looks like:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.ChainedStore', {
    source: TabA.Store // Here store from tab A
});
```